# Replacing white-space / characters with backslashes

Tags: shell, command-line, quoting

I want to convert a bunch of mkvs to mp4s with the following command:

```
for i in $(ls *mkv); do ffmpeg -i $i -vcodec copy -acodec copy $i.mp4; done;
```

However, the filenames have whitespaces and hyphens in them, so the command does not work properly. (When I manually replace `The File - 01.mkv` with `The\ File\ \-\ 01.mkv`, the same command works).

What's the best way to get this to work?

Comment: This is a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/271976). You wanted to do something with files with spaces in their names, but you guessed at a solution and then titled your question with a reference to your guessed solution.

Comment: I don't think any of the answers to that question actually answer this one, though. They're all about `find`.

Answer (score 8):

You need to quote the variables and avoid the command substitution:

```
for i in ./*.mkv; do ffmpeg -i "${i}" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "${i}.mp4"; done
```

See [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary) for a detailed explanation of quoting.

While I'm at it, the above produces files with a `.mkv.mp4` extension; to fix that:

```
for i in ./*.mkv; do ffmpeg -i "${i}" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "${i%%.mkv}.mp4"; done
```

Comment: Or use `zsh` that doesn't have all those misfeatures: `for i (./*.mkv) ffmpeg -i $i -vcodec copy -acodec copy $i:r.mp4`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - it's possible that neither method is foolproof. Apparently [`ffmpeg` interprets its own quotes](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Quoting-and-escaping) - single quotes, backslashes, and double-quotes, though at a glance it appears it interprets double-quotes as the harder form. *Note that you may need to add a second level of escaping when using the command line or a script, which depends on the syntax of the adopted shell language.*